# Join 3 rows on a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame`that looks like this

```
     a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i
0  NaN  NaN  NaN   15   23   71  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   45   31   85  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   52   66   28
```

and I want to join the three rows as the following
**Expected result** :

```
     a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i
0   45   31   85   15   23   71   52   66   28
```